# Weird UITabBar background issue on iPhone6 Simulator, iOS8

Tags: xcode, uitabbarcontroller, ios8, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Hi I have weird problem on iPhone6, iOS8 in iPhone simulator (unfortunately I don't have actual device to test yet).

I have background view whose bottom edge is exactly to top edge of UITabBar 0px overlap, background is in golden colour.

This problem only occurs on iPhone6, on iPhone6 plus and iPhone5 all is ok.

Tab bar on iPhone6 simulator:

[image]

Same tabbar on iPhone6 Plus simulator:

[image]

Same on iPhone5:

[image]

Anyone experienced anything similar?
Do you have any suggestion how to fix this?
Should I ignore it, if its simulator only issue?

Comment: Have similar issue right now. Seems that blur effect is not applied to TabBar background, but on iPhone 6 everything looks great. For me it bugs only when taking screenshots for AppStore

Comment: Check if clip subviews is enabled on view adjacent to the UITabBar

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the @3x, @2x, @1x image size? sometimes is has an issue with those assets.

Comment: It might be the case, since my asset has only one size (its used as blurred background), I will check.

Comment: Did you check your UITabBar's ViewMode? set to Scale to Fill? also the background color and BarTint? you can check it through your storyboard or [UITabBarItem appearance] like this [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]].

did you set it like that?